# What is the total differential used for?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was reading through all of these explanation of what a total differential is and how it looks. But what is it used for? Why would someone want to know a small change dz? The book highlights the similarity with one viariable calculus, where dy=f'(x)dx, this for me is just a way to rearrange dy/dx=f'(x) to integrate and find y=f(x), not to know the small change of dy because it is not used for anything. Am I missing some concept? I know is rather a simple question, but I would appreciate some help

Comment: You may find these interesting -- a total derivative is related to differential forms (a generalization of curl, divergence, etc): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative